# Curl: Bypass proxy for localhost

Tags: bash, curl, proxy

I'm under a proxy, and if I try `curl http://localhost/mysite` or `curl http://127.0.0.1/mysite` curl try to resolve it with the proxy. So I tried with `--noproxy` option, but doesn't work. Is working ok for external servers with the proxy as `curl http://mysite.com`.

#### My configuration:

- Cygwin (bash) under Windows 8 with curl extension.
- Proxy: `proxy.domain.xx:1080` without authentication
- `http_proxy=http://proxy.domain.xx:1080`
- Local Server: XAMP Version 1.8.0
- Apache ports: 80,443
- Browser: Chrome with proxy, but configured to access to `localhost` and `*.dev`

#### From the curl --help

> --noproxy : Comma-separated list of hosts which do not use proxy

#### What I tried:

- I have deactivated the firewall and nothing
- `$ curl -v http://localhost/mysite`  -> Debug:

  **Response**

  ```
  Connected to proxy.domain.xx (200.55.xxx.xx) port 1080 (#0)
  GET http://localhost/mysite HTTP/1.1
  User-Agent: curl/7.21.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) libcurl/7.21.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.3
  Host: localhost
  Accept: */*
  Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
  The system returned: <PRE><I>(111) Connection refused</I></PRE>
  ```
- `curl -v --noproxy localhost, http://localhost/muestra`

  **Response**

  ```
  About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
  * Trying 127.0.0.1... 
  * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
  > GET /mysite HTTP/1.1
  > User-Agent: curl/7.21.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) libcurl/7.21.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.3
  > Host: localhost
  > Accept: */*
  >
  < HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
  < Server: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4
  < Location: http://localhost/mysite
  < Content-Length: 331
  < Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
  ```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `export no_proxy=localhost`?

Comment: The same thing... `301 Moved Permanently`(--noproxy) or `(111) Connection refused` (default use)

Comment: I would say `--noproxy` works from your debugging info.  `301 Moved Permanently` means something else: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301

Answer (score 58, accepted):

After

```
curl -v --noproxy localhost, http://localhost/muestra
```

curl responded with

```
About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
* Trying 127.0.0.1... 
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
```

So it clearly stated that it connected to localhost.

Comment: Three years later and so very helpful!

Comment: @BlakeNeal sorry mate, 2021 here. still helpful :)

Answer (score 14):

try below, to bypass proxy service for local ips

```
export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1
```

Comment: @JJJ, It will bypass proxy service for local addresses.

Comment: And this will work not only for curl but for all commands run on the CLI.

Answer (score 9):

use

curl -v --noproxy '*' http://abc.com

to completely disable proxy.

or if you want to disable proxy for only abc.com destination

curl -v --noproxy "abc.com" http://abc.com

where abc.com is the url you want to go

Answer (score 5):

As some others said, the `--noproxy` options is what you are looking for.
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--noproxy

Apparently, the second request you tried was receiving a HTTP 301 response, so you probably also want to use the `-L` option to follow redirects:
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-L

You can alias curl to always ignore proxies for localhost requests.

`alias curl='curl --noproxy localhost,127.0.0.1'`

Add it to your .bashrc file for convenience:

`echo "alias curl='curl --noproxy localhost,127.0.0.1'" >> ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 5):

In Windows, the following option worked for me for connecting to localhost.

> curl --proxy "" --location http://127.0.0.1:8983

Comment: mine worked also without the `--location` option. Is there a reason for it?

Answer (score 1):

Curl expects the port to be specified with proxy this solution worked for me

export http_proxy="http://myproxy:80"

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can just unset the variable http_proxy before running your curl without the option --noproxy.